# Create a string of same size of another one

Tags: string, bash

In a bash script, I want to write something like:

```
=====================================
= Doing something in THIS_DIRECTORY =
=====================================
```

Actually in my script I use:

```
echo "====================================="
echo "= Doing something in $VARIABLE ="
echo "====================================="
```

This works only if `$VARIABLE` value has the right length, otherwise there will be a misalignment, like appears below:

```
=====================================
= Doing something in THIS_IS_ANOTHER_DIRECTORY =
=====================================
```

How can I change length of upper and lower strings dynamically in order to maintain the same length of middle row?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
VARIABLE="foobar"
X="= Doing something in $VARIABLE ="
echo "${X//?/=}"
echo "$X"
echo "${X//?/=}"
```

Output:

```
=============================
= Doing something in foobar =
=============================
```

Comment: That's clever (far more than my loop).

Comment: Thanks a lot this is exacly what I needed.

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'h;s/./=/g;H;G' <<<"= Doing something in $VARIABLE ="
```

EDIT:

Copy the original string  in the pattern space (PS) to the hold space (HS), replace every character in the PS with an `=`, then append the PS to the HS and lastly append the HS to the PS and print out the PS.

Comment: It looks very good! Could you provide some explanation on how it works?

Answer (score 2):

One way is to calculate the length of $VARIABLE and then echo equal-to(`=`) based on that.

```
var=$(echo "= Doing something in ${variable} =")
equal=$(printf "%-"${#var}"s" "=")
echo "${equal// /=}"; echo ${var}; echo "${equal// /=}"
```

`var` will contain the middle line text.
`${#var}` will return the length of the middle line.

Comment: Thanks this can be easily inserted into a function that's what I want to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that:

```
writenchar() {
  local length=$1
  local char=$2

  for (( i = 0; i < $length; ++i )); do
    echo -n "$char"
  done
}
```

You would have to compute the length of middle string:

```
declare middleString="= Doing something in ${VARIABLE} ="
declare border=$(writenlchar "${#middleString}" '=')
```

And echo it:

```
echo "${border}"
echo "${middleString}"
echo "${border}"
```

Since it is a loop, I store the result in a variable because it will cost less. 
If you don't want that, then the code would look like this:

```
writenlchar "${#middleString}" '='
echo ""
echo "${middleString}"
writenlchar "${#middleString}" '='
echo ""
```

The empty echo are here to dump a newline.

Tell me if it works (I did not test).

Answer (score 1):

Another way that allows you to add coloring

```
#!/bin/bash

function pretty_p {
    # Pretty-print a header
    echo -e "\e[00;32m"
    for i in in $(seq 1 ${#1}); do printf "%s" "=";done;echo
    echo $1
    for i in in $(seq 1 ${#1}); do printf "%s" "=";done
    echo -e "\e[00m"
}


VARIABLE="foobar"
X="= Doing something in $VARIABLE ="

pretty_p "$X"
```

Output (black-n-white unfortunately instead of cool grenish):

```
==============================
= Doing something in foobar =
==============================
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `printf` with `seq` to expand to the desired length.

```
var="= Doing something in $VARIABLE ="
equals=$(printf "%0.s=" $(seq ${#var}))
printf "$equals\n$var\n$equals\n"
```